# Use *.dll as "Pinvoke collection"

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I got a Project with several classes which should work like a P/Invoke collection for me.

For example

```
namespace Win32
{
    static class Winspool
    {
        [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetPrinterData(
            IntPtr hPrinter,
            string pValueName,
            out uint pType,
            byte[] pData,
            uint nSize,
            out uint pcbNeeded);
    }
}
```

The project is much bigger and got only DllImports,  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)], Flags, Structs, Enums etc. a lot of things from the win32 api.

The project should be compiled to a dll-file because I need to call several Win32 functions here and there in my projects and dont want the dllimport declerations in my code.

My question now: Is it possible to use this dll in any other C#-Project and call the imported functions?

I've tried to add my dll via reference but I was not able to call anything out of my dll.

Comment: A winapi function like this is not that easy to use correctly, GetPrinterData() must be called twice.  First with a null argument so you can know the required buffer size.  And you should throw an exception when the function fails.  Always throw an exception on function failure, very important to have a shot at getting a right.  You have an obvious opportunity here to write little wrapper methods that takes care of these details.  Make *those* public.

Comment: Jip I know, thank you. Working with printers and driver in c++ for a while now, just wanted to give P/Invoke a try with it because I'm pretty familiar with the Print Spooler API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your class is not `public`, it will have the default visibility of `internal` and will not be visible from outside its own assembly.

So if you make it `public`:

```
public static class Winspool
{
}
```

Then you can access it from other assemblies:

```
Win32.Winspool.GetPrinterData(...);
```

Comment: Oh wow you're right... had my head full of imports that i didn't recognized that, thank you a lot

Comment: No problem. Common problem, not at all related to P/Invoke, though I couldn't find a duplicate.

Comment: Well seems to be good to know that you can make a p/invoke collection dll at all